# In coffeescript, what's the difference between "is not" and "!="?

Tags: coffeescript

I've got this line of code:

```
console.log "source = #{@source.alignment} unit = #{unit.alignment}: " + (@source.alignment is not unit.alignment)
```

This is printing this out to the console:

> source = good unit = bad: **false**

Why is it printing "false"?  Shouldn't it be printing "true"?  Logically, good "is not" bad.

This

```
console.log "source = #{@source.alignment} unit = #{unit.alignment}: " + (@source.alignment != unit.alignment)
```

prints

> source = good unit = bad: **true**

as expected.

What's the difference?  When should I use `is not`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an operator precedence issue:

```
a is not b => a is (not b)
```

That means that this compiles to the next js:

```
a === !b
```

In your case, b is unit.alignment, and as that var exists and its value is not falsy, !unit.alignment returns false

To solve your problem, check out `isnt` operator [in Coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#operators)